# Printing from TWebBrowser with margins set to 0

Tags: delphi, printing, ole, twebbrowser

I'm printing an HTML document from my application using a `TWebBrowser`:

```
var WebHTML : TWebBrowser;
//Code to set up my TWebBrowser...

//Print the document:
WebHTML.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER);  //or OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
```

How can I set the margins to zero in the printout?

I've tried using `WebHTML.Margins.SetBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);`, but the printout still has margins 0.75in.  I've also set the padding and margins to zero in my CSS:

```
@page {
      margin: 0in;
      padding: 0in;
}
```

I think the problem is the printout is using the margin values set on the Page Setup dialog.  I know this because when I call `WebHTML.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PAGESETUP, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);`, all margins are set to 0.75in... Which matches the margins in my printout.

[image: Page Setup Dialog with 0.75in margins]

I want to control these values without presenting the Page Setup dialog to the user.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) setting `padding` using `@page` at-rule is pointless, because it clearly says that the rule only targets page's dimensions, orientation and margins. By default `<body>` element has some margins too. Did you reset it (`body { margin: 0; }`) in your CSS?

Comment: @PeterWolf Thanks. I have `margin` and `padding` set to zero in the body as well..  I'm basically setting the margin/padding to zero wherever I can - but the 0.75in still appears.

Comment: "_Wherever_" would be `* { margin: 0 }`.

Comment: @AmigoJack I've tried that as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin settings are saved and loaded using Windows Registry keys.  I wrote code to change the keys at the location "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup".  The values margin_bottom, margin_left, margin_right, and margin_top can be set to 0.

[image: Internet Explorer Page Setup registry keys]